# Java copying 1/3rd elements of list to newly created three lists

Tags: java, arraylist

Lets suppose I have `list=[0,1,2,3,4,5]` (always divisible by three like 6,9,12,15.. items). I want to create new three lists and copy 1/3 of this list to each newly created list.

Example of this list will be:

```
newlist1=[0,1]
newlist2=[2,3]
newlist3=[4,5]
```

My actual code:

```
int equalPart=numberOfVms/3; // 3rd part of VM's is going in each node type 
//putting vms for each list . number of vms = number of items in listfor vm 
System.out.println("equal parts =" +equalPart); 
for(int div=0 ; div<numberOfVms; div++) { 
    = listForVm.get(div); 
}
```

Hopefully, the question is clear.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BackSlash STUCK here
int equalPart=numberOfVms/3; // 3rd part of VM's is going in each node type
   //putting vms for each list . number of vms = number of items in listfor vm
   System.out.println("equal parts =" +equalPart);
   for(int div=0 ; div<numberOfVms; div++)
   {
    = listForVm.get(div);
   }

Comment: now i am stuck inside loop

Comment: [Lists.partition()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 you can use :

```
int size = list.size() / 3;
List<List<Integer>> result = IntStream.range(0, 3)
        .mapToObj(l -> list.subList(l * size, (l + 1) * size))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Outputs

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

---

Before you arrive to this part you have to check the size and the number of partitions, else you will get an exception.